# Using __getitem__ in operator overloading with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I do something like this using `__getitem__`?

```
class Computers:

    def __init__(self, processor, ram, hard_drive):
        self.processor = processor 
        self.ram = ram
        self.hard_drive = hard_drive
```

what I want to be able to do is

```
C = Computers('2.4 Ghz','4 gb', '500gb')
```

`C['h']` to return 500gb

and `C['p','r','h']` to return ('2.4 Ghz','4 gb', '500gb')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. In both cases, your `__getitem__` method would be called with one object. In the first case, you are passed a single string object, in the second, you passed a *tuple* containing 3 strings.

Handle both cases:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    attrmap = {'p': 'processor', 'r': 'ram', 'h': 'hard_drive'}
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return getattr(self, attrmap[item])
    # assume a sequence
    return tuple(getattr(self, attrmap[i]) for i in item)
```

Demo, including error handling:

```
>>> C = Computers('2.4 Ghz','4 gb', '500gb')
>>> C['h']
'500gb'
>>> C['p', 'r', 'h']
('2.4 Ghz', '4 gb', '500gb')
>>> C['f']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'f'
>>> C['p', 'r', 'f']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in __getitem__
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <genexpr>
KeyError: 'f'
```